# in iBatis, how can I use 'JOIN' with null property?

Tags: java, sql, join, null, ibatis

I'm studying Java with iBatis.

```
class Player{
   private String name

   private Team team
}
```

In this example, Team can be null or not.

How can I find All Player?

My query is

```
select p.name, p.team_id as 'team.id' from player p join team t on t.id = p.team_id
```

So, If I meet the null property on team, My result is break.

How can I process a null property?

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.name, p.team_id as 'team.id' 
from player p 
left join team t on t.id = p.team_id
```